# Binary Tree Java code

Tags: java, data-structures

I write the following piece of code to add nodes and find them in a Binary tree but when execute it there is no result returned and even there is no error message returned so please tell me what i have to do with my code it's make me disappointed please if there is any help

Here is my Code :

```
public class BinaryTree {
    Node root;

    public void addnode(int key, String name) {
        Node newNode = new Node(key, name);
        if (root == null) {
            root = newNode;
        } else {
            Node focusNode = root;
            Node parent;

            while (true) {
                parent = focusNode;
                if (key < focusNode.key) {
                    focusNode = focusNode.leftChild;
                    if (focusNode == null) {
                        parent.leftChild = newNode;
                        return;
                    } else {
                        focusNode = focusNode.rightChild;
                        if (focusNode == null) {
                            parent.rightChild = newNode;
                            return;
                        }
                    }

                }
            }
        }
    }

    public Node findNode(int key) {
        Node focusNode = root;
        while (focusNode.key != key) {

            if (key < focusNode.key) {

                focusNode = focusNode.leftChild;
            } else {

                focusNode = focusNode.rightChild;
            }
            if (focusNode == null)
                return null;

        }
        return focusNode;

    }

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        BinaryTree theTree = new BinaryTree();

        theTree.addnode(1, "Ahmad");
        theTree.addnode(2, "Ali");
        theTree.addnode(3, "Sara");
        theTree.addnode(4, "Abed");
        theTree.addnode(5, "Mohammad");

        System.out.println("Search for 4");
        System.out.println(theTree.findNode(4));

    }
}

class Node {
    int key;
    String name;

    Node leftChild;
    Node rightChild;

    Node(int key, String name) {
        this.key = key;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return name + "  has a key " + key;
    }
}
```

Comment: `if (focusNode == null) return null;` should be the first line of `findNode`

Comment: And your insertion is incorrect, because you are missing a `}` curly bracket before `else` in order to actually put the node on the right - see, this is why I recommend `Allman Code Style` instead of `K&R` even in Java - I've debugged code just by formatting it to show the blocks.

Comment: Please can u edit it and send it again to me please

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with placing braces in wrong position.Just replace the addnode method with this one

```
public void addnode(int key, String name) {
    Node newNode = new Node(key, name);
    if (root == null) {
        root = newNode;
        System.out.println("Inserted : "+newNode);
    } else {
        Node focusNode = root;
        Node parent;

        while (true) {
            parent = focusNode;
            if (key < focusNode.key) {
                focusNode = focusNode.leftChild;
                if (focusNode == null) {
                    parent.leftChild = newNode;
                    System.out.println("Inserted : "+newNode);
                    return;
                }
            }
            else {
                    focusNode = focusNode.rightChild;
                    if (focusNode == null) {
                        parent.rightChild = newNode;
                        System.out.println("Inserted : "+newNode);
                        return;
                    }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the below piece of `else` should be attached to  `if (key < focusNode.key)` part.

```
else {
    focusNode = focusNode.rightChild;
    if (focusNode == null) {
        parent.rightChild = newNode;
        return;
    }   
}
```

What you've done (by mistake probably) is you've written it after `if (focusNode == null) {`, which means your code doesn't take care of `key > focusNode.key` at all. Once you fix that, you code runs normally.

Now, the important part is how you could find this bug *yourself*. You can probably add a couple of `System.out.println` statements in the beginning of the while loop and check the values of few variables at every iteration. Obviously, if you use an IDE, you can set breakpoints and debug that way too.